# Developer options reset after reboot

Tags: cyanogenmod, settings

Anyone have any idea why certain developer options (e.g. Disable HW overlays) seem to reset whenever rebooting the device, and/or how to resolve it?

Comment: Which CM build are you using and on which device? Does the problem persist with other CM builds as well, preferably with a stable build?

Comment: @Firelord 12.1 Hammerhead. I'm not sure if it occurs with other builds, but this one is a snapshot.